# ¿Se puede modificar el archivo host de tal manera que se pueda leer pero no modificar?

Tags: web, seguridad, ip

```
Quiero evitar que mi pc acceda a sitios con contenido para adultos y pare esto modifique el archivo host agregándole las ip´s de safesearch de Google:
216.239.38.120 www.google.com
216.239.38.120 www.google.ca
216.239.38.120 plus.google.com
```

Pero cada vez que alguien quiere acceder al archivo lo puede modificar. He optado por modificar las propiedades para permitir solo su lectura pero de igual manera aun sigue siendo un problema ya que se puede deshacer el cambio.
También le coloque contraseña al archivo y me dice que el sistema no puede leerlo, por lo que da error al iniciar el navegador. Y tampoco quiero crear un usuario con permisos restringidos porque es muy engorroso, SOLO QUIERO QUE ESE ARCHIVO PERMANESCA INTOCABLE PARA QUE NADIE PUEDA VER PORNO EN MI PC.
Si alguien tiene una solución le estaría muy agradecido si la comparte.

Comment: Es mejor hacer el bloque directamente en el router.